# Import php class from external folder in Cakephp without vendors

Tags: php, api, cakephp, external, vendors

I need to import external apis to cakephp without using vendors.
On the same servidor I have the following folders:

```
wwww/myapi/myclass.php
wwww/web/app/vendors
```

`myapi` can be used from other applications that's why i don't want to include it in cakephp folders.

Answer (score 0):

Use a symbolic link.

```
ln -s www/myapi/myclass.php www/web/app/vendors/myapi/myclass.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried include('../../../myapi/myclass.php); ?
Also, if it's not a huge file you could just copy it into vendors or into your webroot folder...

Comment: I had included to my php.ini `include_path = ".;C:\wamp\www\MyApiPath\"` but I believe it isn't the best way to deal with api includes... (it's close to your solution without using relative path)

Comment: Yeah, windows sucks.  The best way on linux or unix would def be the symbolic link, but on windows i think you are best off just including the php file into whatever project you are doing, which also makes more sense if you will be moving the code in the future, because your include will be broken.  Most API's i don't think are big enough to worry about taking up the extra space, and making sure your code doesn't break when moved is pretty important also.  Good Luck!